# Python3 Trace back issue

Tags: python-3.x

First, let me disclaim that I am extremely new to the coding world and work requires me to use Python going forward. My experience is limited to having just completed SANS 573.

I'm trying to obtain the Date and Time from image files in their various formats. Excuse the example, I'm just using this to try and get it working.

This what I currently have:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

L88 = Path("L88.jpg")

def corvette(L88):
    imgobj=Image.open(L88)
    info=imgobj._getexif()
    return info[36867]
```

```
>>> corvette(L88)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in corvette
KeyError: 36867
>>>
```

I am running the function from the desktop which is where I have the image currently saved.

I don't understand the error messages.

KeyError: 36867 also has me confused too as when I looked up the tag, that is what I found and what worked when I just did my course.

Comment: Whatever is `info`, it does not have an element number 36867. Why do you think it does? Where does this number come from?

Comment: Because when I run
```
TAGS[36867]
'DateTimeOriginal'
```
is displayed.

Comment: What is `TAGS`?

Answer (score 0):

The `_getexif()` method returns a Python datastructury called a *dictionary*.

The *values* in a dictionary are accessed by their *key*.
In this case, the keys are numbers.
Not all keys are mandatory. You can use the `keys()` method to see which ones exist. Try:

```
print(info.keys())
```

to see which keys exist.

You can also test if a key exists:

```
if 36867 in info:
    return info[36867]
else:
    return None
```

Note that there is a mapping between these numbers and their exif tags names available.
You can use that to create a readable dictionary.

Note that *not all JPEG images have EXIF information*. In that case, the `_getexif()` method returns `None`, so you should take that into account and test for that:

```
from PIL import Image, ExifTags


def image_info(path):
    imgobj = Image.open(path)
    info = imgobj._getexif()
    if info is None:
        return None
    rv = {
        ExifTags.TAGS[key]: info[key]
        for key in info.keys()
    }
    return rv
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Unfortunately I still get the same errors with the addition of File "<stdin>", line 4, in <dictcomp>

When I run TAGS[key] it works by itself.

Comment: Can you add a link to the image in your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, doing more course work. The image on my desktop, how do I do what you requested please?